# I met with/met my friend in florida (In case of unplanned, accidental meetup)

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

Met is transitive verb in case of planned action. However, if i met my friend accidentally in florida should i use preposition with or not

Comment: [UK] I think you need "I happened to meet..." or "[Quite] by chance I met..." Or (informally) "I bumped into..." "To meet _with_ (someone)" is a recent innovation and means the same as "to meet (up with) someone".

Comment: "ran into" or "bumped into"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find regional variations of interpretation, but from a native British English perspective:

> I met with my friend in Florida.

suggests a longer or planned meeting.

> I met my friend in Florida.

suggests a planned meeting.  It could also be understood to mean the first time you met this person who is now your friend was in Florida.

More colloquially we might say:

> I bumped into my friend in Florida.

> I ran into my friend in Florida.

> I ran across my friend in Florida.

All imply the meeting was unplanned but could also be misunderstood to mean literal actions of running or bumping.

Old Brixtonian's suggestion is good:

> I happened to meet my friend in Florida.